# Es necesario conectar a la base de datos cada vez que se realiza una consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Es una duda o curiosidad que me pregunto, porque en mi código cada vez que voy a ser una consulta hago:

`self::connect()->prepare(SELECT * FROM TABLE)`

Connect es una función en donde declaro todos los valores de la base de datos y hago la conexión y la retorno, no sería consumir mucho recurso? O sea cada vez volviendo a llamar a la función connect y volviendo a conectar, no hay alguna manera de mantener la variable conexión intacta?

Comment: No, no es necesario, de hecho, `self:connect()` debería devolver siempre la misma conexión para evitar consumir recursos innecesariamente.

Comment: Cada vez que realizas una operación en la base, debes conectarte por precaución, no debes asumir que la conexión esta siempre open, lo que si debes hacer por precaución y por no agotar los recursos del servidor es cerrar las conexiones cada vez que hayas ejecutado una operación, pero creo que el RDBMS también tiene un parámetro de cierre de conexiones.

Answer (score 0):

puedes guardar esa conexion en una variable llamada `$conexion` y la defines al inicio de tu documento, despues solo llama la variable `$conexion` cuando lo requieras